# How to create a line feature which contains the overlying polygon attributes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I have a road network Shapefile which intersects a polygon feature class. I need to
create a excel table which contains the road number, the attribute from the intersecting polygon feature class and the kilometer from which the polygon intersects the line.

Imagine a line 10km long which intersects 3 polygons between the start to the finish. I need a table which tells me the following:

```
ROAD   From KM    NAME
L242      0      Smith
L242     3.4     Jones
L242     6.2     Andrews
```

I have ESRI Advanced licenses with network analyst and FME.

Would this be a job for the Linear Referencing toolset?

Comment: They look like point events in Linear Referencing to me but that may not be the only possible solution in ArcGIS Desktop.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a proper line network dataset, particularly direction of traverse is correct:

- Copy your lines as M values are enabled (if the SHAPE is not Polyline M, see https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/output-has-m-values.htm);
- Intersect you lines with the polygons as selecting output type Point;
- Use Linear Referencing Toolbar to **Create Routes**;
- Use again Linear Referencing Toolbar to **Locate Features Along
  Routes** by setting points as Input Features against your route.

This should list which route items intersecting with events (i.e., polygon boundaries) as keeping the event IDs, by which you can join to get any other attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create a spatial join:

- Right click on the polygon layer → Joins and Relates → Join
- Select *Join data from another layer based on spatial location*
- Select *Each polygon will be given all the attributes...*

The result will be added to the map automatically. You can copy/paste the attribute table to Excel, or use `arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion` ([documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-excel.htm)) .

The resulting shapefile will contain records for all polygons, even the ones that do not intersect any line. If that's the case for you, you could remove those polygons in advance.